# I have a table, how do I call from it based on option select drop-downs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of pricing based on certain parameters, I'm familiar with the  and  tags at this point. I would like to know what is the most efficient way to call for a square foot cost based on the selections of three different drop down box selections. The three different boxes would be something along the lines of what code is shown below.

```
<td> <select id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
<option value="0">Select Glass Pattern</option>
<option value="1">Autumn Leaves</option>
<option value="2">Treebark</option>
</select></td>

 <td> <select id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
<option value="0">Select Glass Thickness</option>
<option value="4">5/32 (4mm)</option>
<option value="10">3/8 (10mm)</option>
</select></td>

<td> <select id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
<option value="0">Select Glass Type</option>
<option value="1">Tempered</option>
<option value="2">Annealed</option>
</select></td>
```

How would I be able to call the appropriate cost from the table below? Given that from the drop-down boxes, I select Tempered Autumn Leaves in 5/32 thickness, to call for the square foot Cost of 27$, versus getting 17$ for the annealed format

```
Select Glass    Select Thickness    Tempered or Annealed?   Cost
Autumn Leaves      5/32(4mm)              Tempered         $27.00
Autumn Leaves      5/32(4mm)              Annealed         $17.00
Treebark           5/32(4mm)              Tempered         $31.00
Treebark           5/32(4mm)              Annealed         $19.00
```

Comment: Can you show code for calculate() function.

Comment: @SaileshChowdaryDoppalapudi I can, but it doesn't necessarily match up with what I have posted above. the Calculate function is based on definites at the moment. I'm looking to integrate the result of this question into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Titel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <select id="box1" onchange="calculate()">
            <option value="">Select Glass Pattern</option>
            <option value="0">Autumn Leaves</option>
            <option value="1">Treebark</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id="box2" onchange="calculate()">
            <option value="">Select Glass Thickness</option>
            <option value="0">5/32 (4mm)</option>
            <option value="1">3/8 (10mm)</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id="box3" onchange="calculate()">
            <option value="">Select Glass Type</option>
            <option value="0">Tempered</option>
            <option value="1">Annealed</option>
        </select>
        <div id="output">Please select all three values</div>
        </div>
        <script>

            let calculate = () => {
                let box1_selection = getValueById("box1");
                let box2_selection = getValueById("box2");
                let box3_selection = getValueById("box3");

                if(box1_selection == "" || box2_selection == "" || box3_selection == "") {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please select all three values";
                } else {
                    let value = "not specified";

                    /*if(box2_selection == 0 && box3_selection == 0 {
                        value = "$27.00";
                    } else if(box2_selection == 0 && box3_selection == 1) {
                        value = "$17.00";
                    }*/
                    value = getPrice(box1_selection, box2_selection, box3_selection);

                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = value;
                }
            }

            let getValueById = (id) => {
                let selection = document.getElementById(id);
                return selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
            }

            let getPrice = (value_1, value_2, value_3) => {
                // price_data is a 3 dimensional array.
                let price_data = [
                    [
                        ["$27.00", "$17.00"],
                        ["not specified", "not specified"]
                    ],
                    [
                        ["$27.00", "$17.00"],
                        ["not specified", "not specified"]
                    ]
                ];
                return price_data[value_1][value_2][value_3];
            }
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This solves your question. You need to use onselect and not oninput. Also, IDs need to be unique. Per selection, the values the options can take should be unique too. You see this in my example. My calculate function prints the result by the values you provided by your table. You can extend the calculate function for other combinations. As you see, the first selections value isn't important for the result and the second selection can only have one value to result in a real price.

edit: In this version, you can use either the function to calculate the price, or the if-else construct. The if-else part should be straight forward. In the getPrice function, i use a 3dimensional array. The first dimension is for the value in box1, the second for the value in box2 and the third for the value in box3. See those dimensions as paths in a graph. If you follow those paths, you will get to your specifiedprice. The if-else part is also there, so you can use whatever you like. Also i extracted the code to get the value of a html-selection. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm a little lost in your code, what would I need to call to, to set a variable that is equal to the output of that function?

Comment: The function has no output. The calculate-function is not that hard. Just try to understand it step by step. At first, i get the selection elements. That are the lines with "let box1 = document......" to "let box3 = document...". In the next three linex, i get the selected values of the selections. Then there is an if-else construct to calculate your price by the values the user selected. Have a look at the values in the html part, and afterwards at this if-else construct. If this calculation is your problem, i can write you another,more complete version.

Comment: let getValueById = (id) => {
 let selection = document.getElementById(id);
 return selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
}
This code gets you the value of a selection. Just use:
let value = getValueById("box1");
for example.

Comment: I'm trying to multiply the selected output by another variable. I tried using the data from box1 but it didn't lead to a value

Comment: Maybe you try to multiply a string with a number? You can make a number out of a string with the plus sign. Example: 1337 * +"42". So you just have to put a + in front of your string value, in your case in front of your value. So maybe something like 1337 * +value;

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to give your various `<option>` elements different `value` attributes so you can distinguish them. I'd recommend giving the 'selection' default an empty string, and unique identifiers for the other selections.

Then you need to work out which value is selected, which can be done with `element.options[element.selectedIndex].value`, after the element has been obtained with `document.getElementById()`. Keep in mind this will need to be done **inside** of the function, as the value will update!

Finally, just check that none of the three values are an empty string, which will mean that they've been selected. From here, I've just outputted the entered values, but you can do whatever calculations you need.

You'll probably only want raw **integers** for the `Tempered` / `Annealed` values, but I've gone with strings to showcase output clearer in the following example:

```js
function calculate() {
  var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");
  box1_value = box1.options[box1.selectedIndex].value;

  var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
  box2_value = box2.options[box2.selectedIndex].value;

  var box3 = document.getElementById("box3");
  box3_value = box3.options[box3.selectedIndex].value;

  console.clear(); // Reset the output
  
  if (box1_value != "" && box2_value != "" && box3_value != "") {
    console.log(box1_value, box2_value, box3_value);
  }
}
```

```html
<td>
  <select id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
    <option value="">Select Glass Pattern</option>
    <option value="Autumn Leaves">Autumn Leaves</option>
    <option value="Treebark">Treebark</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  <select id="box2" oninput="calculate()">
    <option value="">Select Glass Thickness</option>
    <option value="5/32 (4mm)">5/32 (4mm)</option>
    <option value="3/8 (10mm)">3/8 (10mm)</option>
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  <select id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
    <option value="">Select Glass Type</option>
    <option value="Tempered - $27">Tempered</option>
    <option value="Annealed - $17">Annealed</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: I see, for the sake of my argument, I forgot to make the different patterns different prices, because that is the case most of the time, just not with this instance. See my edit to the original post above. Also, how would I be able to call that value and set it as a variable? Would      var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box3').value; work?

Comment: You would need to use **both** of my two lines to grab the value. For example, my `box1_value` is a variable that holds the **updated** selection's value of `#box1`. As one line it would be rather complex: `document.getElementById("box1").options[document.getElementById("box1").selectedIndex].value`. As for different patterns costing different amounts, you'd simply set the `value` of the pattern options, and then you can do some sort of calculation based on those variables in the `if` condition of my example.